# Example of a nilpotent matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to find a real square matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ such that $(I-A)B = I, B(I-A) = I$, in case $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ is nilpotent.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is nilpotent, all eigenvalues are zero, hence $I-A$ is invertible.
Take  $B=(I-A)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

If $A^n=0$, then $B=I+A+\cdots+A^{n-1}$ for 
$$
(I-A)B=I-A^n=I
$$

Answer (score 1):

If $A^n=0$, then you can take $B=I+A+A^2+\cdots+A^{n-1}$.

This is motivated by the series
$$
\frac1{1-z} = 1 + z + z^2 + \cdots
$$

Answer (score 0):

$(I-A)B=I=B(I-A)\implies B$ is inverse of $(I-A)$ i.e.

$B=(I-A)^{-1}=I+A+A^2+...+A^{n-1}$